# Passing html button tag with url href to template

Tags: python, html, django

I have a code that reads some data from firebase as well as a button which has html tags and a url href and then it passes into my html template and into a table.

My `urls.py` is formatted like this:

`path('history-report/', view.history_report, name="historyreport")`

*In my views I pass the values like this*:

```
def history_report(request):
     
# retrieving information code

ziplist=zip(history, date)
            
view_button='<a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="view_history" 
value={0} href="{% url 'historyreport' %}">View</a>'.format(history)
         
return render(request,'history.html',
{"history":ziplist,"view_button":view_button})
```

This lead me to a 500 error.

**Note that my page works fine if i remove the URL**:

`{% url 'historyreport' %}`

I tried using this instead:
`href='/historyreport'`

But this redirects me to the `localhost/mycurrentpage/historyreport`

when it should have been `localhost/historyreport`

Any suggestions on how i can get this to work?

Comment: Try use ../ for the path?

Comment: the 500 error means an internal error occurred check your terminal for what the error is, and post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the curly brackets (`{ … }`) are seen as markers to write data to. We can work with double curly brackets:

```
from django.template import <b>Template, Context</b>

def history_report(request):
    ziplist = zip(history, date)
        
    view_button=Template(
        f'<a type="submit" href="{{% url \'historyreport\' %}}" class="btn btn-primary" name="view_history" value="{history}">View</a>'
    ).render(Context())
     
 return render(request,'history.html', {"history":ziplist,"view_button":view_button})
```

In the template, you then should render the `view_button` with the [**`|safe`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
{{ view_button|safe }}
```

Comment: Should i have the ```<b></b>``` tags in the import? As im getting an invalid syntax error. Also at the ```href="{{% url 'historyreport' %}}"```

Comment: @MasterIrfanElahee: no, that is simply to put something in boldface in the code block. Normally the rendered version looks like `href="{{% url 'historyrepot ' %}}`, the boldface is thus only to draw attention to the essential part of the change.

Comment: im still getting an invalid syntax error on the ```href="{{% url 'historyreport' %}}"```

Comment: @MasterIrfanElahee: did you use the `f'...'` for string interpolation? and remove the `format` part?

Comment: @MasterIrfanElahee: nvm I think I found the error: you should escape the single quotes, since these are part of the *content* of the string.